# Why does the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{1+(x - a)^2}dx$ diverge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Why does the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{1+(x - a)^2}dx$$ diverge? (for any real $a$)

I know one way to prove it is using the comparison rule but I can't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: $x$ or $dx$ at the numerator ?

Comment: it is x, I edited the question to make it clear

Answer (score 4):

$$\int\frac{xdx}{1+(x-a)^2}=\int\frac{(x-a)dx}{1+(x-a)^2}+a\int\frac{dx}{1+(x-a)^2}.$$
Consider first integral in the RHS:
$$\int\frac{x-a}{1+(x-a)^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{d(1+(x-a)^2)}{1+(x-a)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\ln{(1+(x-a)^2)}+C.$$
Now let us compute definite integrals, starting with the second one:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+(x-a)^2}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\pi.$$
The first one, using Newton-Leibniz formula:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{d(1+(x-a)^2)}{1+(x-a)^2}=\lim_{b\to+\infty}\ln(1+b^2)-\lim_{b\to-\infty}\ln(1+b^2).$$
Note that second integral converges and is equal to $\pi$, while the first diverges, because $\ln(1+t^2)$ is not bounded function. Hence, your integral diverges.

Comment: Yes, but what about the definite integral ?

Answer (score 0):

With $x-a=\tan t$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{1+(x - a)^2}dx=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2}a+\tan tdt=\infty$$

Comment: Why infinity when the integrand is an odd function ?